# enum to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting, enums

I have the following code:

```
class mph {
public:
enum minute_periods {five, ten, fifteen, thirty}; 
   std::vector<minute_periods> factors;
  minute_periods fac;

void setUpFactors(void) { 
    factors.resize(4);
    factors[five] = 5;
    factors[ten] = 10;
    factors[fifteen] = 15;
    factors[thirty] = 30;
  }
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘mph::minute_periods’
```

how do I fix it?

Comment: Tell me what you are trying to do. `factors` is an array of enums, so you can't assign `int` values to its elements. Did you mean the assignments the other way around, like `factors[10] = ten;`? Or did you mean `{five = 5...` in the definition of the enums?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve? The bigger picture? There are multiple options depending on your clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int`'s are not implicitly cast to `enum`s, you have to do it explicitly which is why you're getting the error.  I don't think this code will do what you want it to however, it looks like you want something like this.

```
    std::map<minute_periods, int> factors;
```

That way `factors[five]` will give you an int, and not an `enum` like the vector would.  I'm guessing from your code this is what you want because the values 5, 10, 15 and 30 are outside your `enum`'s range (which is from 0 to 3).

Comment: I think for this case, std::vector<int> would suffice. That way he should be able to do `factors[five] = someIntValue`

Comment: when I set it up as a map, I get the following error: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::map<mph::minute_periods, int, std::less<mph::minute_periods>, std::allocator<std::pair<const mph::minute_periods, int> > >::mapped_type’ to ‘mph::minute_periods`

Comment: @user1155299 I did it and didn't get any errors, what is the line that is giving you this error?

Comment: @GuyGreer, I wrote the following line and that is when the map doesn't work...`void setFac(minute_periods v) { fac = factors[v];};`

Comment: @user1155299 this is because factors[v] returns an `int`, and you're trying to store it in an `enum`. What is `fac` going to be used for?  Do you want it to hold the integer values 5, 10, 15, 30 or do you want it to hold the enum values five, ten, fifteen, thirty?

Comment: @user1155299 in the first case I think you want to declare fac as `int fac;` and in the second case I think you want `void setFac(minute_periods v) { fac = v;}`

Comment: @GuyGreer, I want it to hold enum values so let me try the second case

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you can implicitly cast from an `enum` to an `int`, but not the other way around.  You can fix this by using explicit casts:

```
factors.resize(4);
factors[five] = minute_period(5);
factors[ten] = minute_period(10);
factors[fifteen] = minute_period(15);
factors[thirty] = minute_period(30);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @templatetypedef, yes it compiled but I now get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: @BenVoigt- There is a call to `resize` prior to this that I had assumed was in there.  I'll update the answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: @templatetypedef: No, my fault.  I assumed that the enumerands were assigned to `five = 5`, `ten = 10`, etc.  They aren't, so ignore my comment.

Comment: This is going to be confusing. For example, if you add the enums forty and sixty, then you end up with factors[five] == sixty == 5.

Comment: actually the above cast is not working. I printed the output and this is what I get `fac is: 5 ,factors[fac]: 8561 ` where fac is `  minute_periods fac;`

Comment: @user1155299- I think that's because if `fac` is 5, it's out of range for the vector.  None of your enums have value 5, so that's probably a logic error someplace else in the program.  Or do you want the map to invert the mapping so that given a number, you get the enum?

Comment: @templatetypedef, yes indeed. so, should I be writing `factors(unsigned int[five]) = 5`

Comment: @templatetypedef, if you don't mind me asking, is there a way I can get in touch with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only convert enum to ints, not ints to enum. Since your vector is a list of minute_periods, you should only assign minute periods to factors. You probably want

```
factors[five] = five;
factors[ten] = ten;
factors[fifteen] = fifteen;
factors[thirty] = thirty;
```

That will solve your compile error.

Comment: The point of the vector seems to be to convert from the enum to its numeric code.  This will not solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code causes that error to be generated in two places:

- when you use your `enum` values as indices of `vector`
- when you use your `enum` values as values in that vector

Your logic is flawed. `vector` is always indexed by integers. A wild guess would be that you wanted `map<minute_period, int>`, but on second thought - this doesn't make any sense.

To use `enum` values as integers, just do it:

```
enum minute_periods 
{
    five = 5, 
    ten = 10, 
    fifteen = 15, 
    thirty = 30
};
```

This is the correct way to use `enum` values as integers - not some silly data structure converting labels to values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your vector as `std::vector<unsigned int> factors;` if you want to do it that way. If you're converting an enum to a different value through a vector, the value type of the vector should be the type you're converting to. The lookup can be done with the enum as the index through implicit conversion.

I'd also suggest defining a count enum value as the last entry in your list of enum values. It can replace the hard-coded size.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `map` not a `vector`.  Since it appears what you are storing is a map from the enum to an integer - not an a vector of `minute_periods`

```
class mph {
public:
enum minute_periods {five, ten, fifteen, thirty}; 
   std::map<minute_periods, int> factors;

void setUpFactors(void) { 
    factors[five] = 5;
    factors[ten] = 10;
    factors[fifteen] = 15;
    factors[thirty] = 30;
  }
};
```

Also you may just simply what to explicitly set the enum values:

```
class mph {
    public:
    enum minute_periods {five = 5, ten = 10, fifteen = 15, thirty = 30}; 
};
```

Comment: when I set it up as a map, I get the following error: `error: invalid conversion from ‘std::map<mph::minute_periods, int, std::less<mph::minute_periods>, std::allocator<std::pair<const mph::minute_periods, int> > >::mapped_type’ to ‘mph::minute_periods`

Comment: Don't know why you are getting that - just tried the example above and it compiles correctly.